# Make Changes to a TFS Work Item as a specific user

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am working on creating a Web application, which the users in my team will use to 
    make changes to TFS Work Items. I am using TFS API for this..

In order to access the TFS Server , I used my credentials within the Web Application.

Now each time someone uses the application and makes changes to TFS work items, it shows 
  as if I have made changes to these items since my credentials are being used in the application.

Is there a way I can use the credentials of the person logging into my application to show up on TFS as the person making the changes ?

Comment: Make the web app use windows auth and impersonate that user in API calls? (Don't know much about the TFS API or your setup, but assuming you're using Windows accounts you should be able to pass credentials)

Comment: Have you tried `HttpContext.Current.User` ?

Comment: why are you not using the web interface that comes with TFS are you not reinventing the wheel here..?

Comment: @DJ KRAZE .. Yes I know .. There is a certain complex requirement within our team which doesn't allow me to use TFS, and after a lot of thought I came up with this solution.

Comment: you are confusing me first you said you're using TFS now you're saying that you can't use it.. also sounds like if you're using impersonation than that could be a major issue.. you should be able to get a a end users domain name if you are having issues with trying to figure out who's doing what.. are you familiar with `var userName = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];` if not you can use `var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var userFind = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName);`

Comment: Can't they do it via VS or TFS web?

Comment: that's what I already asked him Danish

Comment: `Environment.UserName` you can use that as well ` System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User` or ` System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` there are so many things you can try to capture who.. personally I think that `PrincipalContext is your best bet in this case..

Comment: and if you can't show who's making the changes then write and or create a log that write an entry to the database for anyone that makes the changes and have it email it to yourself if you don't trust your app..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the 'make requests on behalf of others' functionality. You can impersonate another user by following:

```
public void Impersonation(Uri serverUri,string userToImpersonate)
{
    // Read out the identity of the user we want to impersonate
    TeamFoundationIdentity identity = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, 
        userToImpersonate,
        MembershipQuery.None, 
        ReadIdentityOptions.None);

    tfs_impersonated = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(serverUri, identity.Descriptor);

    GetAuthenticatedIdentity(tfs_impersonated);

    // Use this tfs_impersonated object to communicate to TFS as the other users.
}
```

And make sure your account running the website has the permission to "make requests on behalf of others":

[image]
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/104019/TFS-API-Part-TFS-Impersonation

Comment: I see the "Changed By" and "Created By" Property but not the "AutgorisedAs" property for the work item ?

Comment: My bad... updated to reflect what you really need to do.