# How to change the Created By field on a Work Item in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

Is there a way to change the Created By field on a work item in TFS? Maybe by altering the database?

I want to be able to create a bug/feature/PBI, then change it to be created by the member of staff who reported it to me.

This way, I can track who is submitted change requests, and they would also then receive bug update notifications.

Comment: You need to use a feature called "TFS impersonation". This thread can give you more insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965197/make-changes-to-a-tfs-work-item-as-a-specific-user

Comment: @YanSklyarenko Thanks for that, but I don't have a custom web app built for submitting bugs. I've simply allowed access to the official TFS web app by adding the Domain Users (Windows group) to the Stakeholders (TFS group). I'd like to create a web-app like described on that question, but time doesn't permit it right now. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Comment: I'm not sure there's something built-in for this purpose - you'll have to use API.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko I was hoping there might be a row value I can modify the user ID in. I've taken a cursory look into the db, and I'm aware of the risks of modifying it, but so far it's looking like a behemoth.

Answer (score 2):

You can only overwrite the CreatedBy field when create the workitem via API with bypass rule enabled. Refer to this link for details: [Make an update bypassing rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#make-an-update-bypassing-rules).

A quick solution for this would be create a powershell script to create the workitem via Rest API. Sample for your reference:

```
#Input basic information
$collectionuri = "http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/"
$project = "ProjectName"
$workitemtype = 'Task'
$createdby = 'Display Name'
$title = 'Title'

#Create the workitem
$workitem = @(@{op="add";path="/fields/System.Title";value=$title},@{op="add";path="/fields/System.CreatedBy";value=$createdby})
$json = $workitem | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
$headers= @{"Content-Type"="application/json-patch+json"}
$url= $collectionuri + $project + '/_apis/wit/workitems/$' + $workitemtype +'?bypassRules=true&api-version=1.0'
$mycredentials = Get-Credential
$wi = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Patch -Credential $mycredentials -Body $json -ContentType 'application/json-patch+json' 
Write-Host $wi
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want to set a faker creator for a work item.

> **Created By**
>
> The name of the team member who created the work item.
>
> Reference name=Microsoft.VSTS.Common.CreatedBy

There is no build-in way to change this filed. Take a look at this:

> **IsEditable**
>
> No
>
> Indicates if users can modify this field (True) or not (False).
>   **Examples of non-editable fields are ones that are set by the system,** such as the ID, Revision, **Created By**, and Changed By
>   fields.

More details please refer [Work Item Field Attributes – What You Can and Can’t Change](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2012/08/17/work-item-field-attributes-what-you-can-and-cant-change/)

Change the value directly in the Database may do the trick, but it's not a recommend way. It's also go against the concept of source control.

If you just want to notify others when work item update. As a workaround, suggest you use the **[follow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/follow-work-items#follow-a-work-item)**  function in work item.

*When you want to track the progress of a single work item, click the Follow icon icon. This signals the system to notify you when changes are made to the work item.*

***Note:***  This feature is available from TFS 2017 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to update the system field? You may add a new field "Initiator"([Add or modify a field to track work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/add-modify-field)). Set value from Created By on creation. Then update it when you want.