# Can we create a work item on behalf of others in TFS 2018?

Tags: azure, tfs, devops

We have an automation in place to move information from BUG to a customized ticket template (Infra Requests.xml) in case of infrastructural issues. Currently an AD account is being used to create tickets. I want to use the CreatedBy field from Bug to create Infra Requests. I know we have way to check-in behalf and queued-build behalf, wondering if we have similar for create-workitem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a work item and update the CreatedBy field with the bypassRules option. The same question was here: [How to change the Created By field on a Work Item in TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847751/how-to-change-the-created-by-field-on-a-work-item-in-tfs)

Link to rest api: [Work Items - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1)

Comment: @Fairoz mark this post as answer. Maybe somebody`ll find your question useful too.