# How to use TFS REST API for making changes to work item as specified user

Tags: c#, rest, tfs

I need something like [Make Changes to a TFS Work Item as a specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965197/make-changes-to-a-tfs-work-item-as-a-specific-user) but for TFS **REST** API.

So:

```
new WorkItemTrackingHttpClient(new Uri("http://server:8080/tfs"), new VssCredentials(...));
```

what are my next steps?

Answer (score 1):

Impersonate user in Rest API is not supported, it's supported in SOAP API.

There is a [user voice here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/17996818-enable-to-impersonate-user-in-rest-api) to suggest the feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve that in future release...

To update work item with REST API you can try below sample

```
public class TFSClient
{
    public WorkItemTrackingHttpClient WorkItem { get; set; }
    public TFSClient()
    {            
        VssCredentials vssCred = new VssCredentials(new WindowsCredential(true));
        WorkItem = new WorkItemTrackingHttpClient(new Uri(TFSServer.Url), vssCred);
    }
}
 public static object UpdateWorkItemByID(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument
            {
                new JsonPatchOperation()
                {                       
                    Operation = Operation.Add,
                    Path = ItemField.History,
                    Value = "Teste"
                }
            };            
            return  new TFSClient().WorkItem.UpdateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, id).Result;              

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

You can also update the work item by calling REST API with the **specific user** directly:

e.g.:

```
VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain")));
```

Alternately using PowerShell:

```
Param(
   [string]$baseurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection",  
   [string]$workitemid = "39",
   [string]$user = "Domain\user",
   [string]$token = "password"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
write-host $WorkitemType

function CreateJsonBody
{

    $value = @"
[
  {
    "op": "test",
    "path": "/rev",
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "value": "test0909ddd"
  }

]

"@

 return $value
}

$json = CreateJsonBody

$uri = "$baseurl/_apis/wit/workitems/$($workitemid)?api-version=2.2" #_apis/wit/workitems/"+"$"+"bug?api-version=2.2"
Write-Host $uri
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Patch -Body $json -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

Comment: But here the default account is used. I need to use an impersonated user (do changes on behalf of user). Now I see https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/17996818-enable-to-impersonate-user-in-rest-api without an answer. It seems that this is not possible now.

Comment: @Hopeless Yes, investigated again and cannot find a way to impersonate user in REST API. Thanks for sharing the user voice link.. I also updated the answer by adding your comments and other workarounds. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I think the user voice question has been migrated to: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Enable-to-impersonate-user-in-Rest-API/713800